# Highcharts column drilldown, assign two different colours to the two different drilldown columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've been searching everywhere but I can't find out how to add two different colours to two different drilldowns columns using highcharts. I would like to make the first column for each drilldown green and the second column red for each drilldown. At the moment, I can only make both of drilldown columns red.

JS:

```
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2018'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://statcounter.com" target="_blank">statcounter.com</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }

    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
            }
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },

    "series": [
        {
            "name": "Browsers",
            "colorByPoint": true,
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Chrome",
                    "y": 62.74,
                    "drilldown": "Chrome"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Firefox",
                    "y": 10.57,
                    "drilldown": "Firefox"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Internet Explorer",
                    "y": 7.23,
                    "drilldown": "Internet Explorer"
                },

            ]
        }
    ],
    "drilldown": {
        "series": [
            {
                "name": "Chrome",
                "id": "Chrome",
                "color": 'red', 



                "data": [
                    [
                        "v65.0",
                        1,
                    ],
                    [
                        "v64.0",
                        1.3
                    ],

                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Firefox",
                "id": "Firefox",
                "data": [
                    [
                        "v58.0",
                        1.02
                    ],
                    [
                        "v57.0",
                        7.36
                    ],

                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Internet Explorer",
                "id": "Internet Explorer",
                "data": [
                    [
                        "v11.0",
                        6.2
                    ],
                    [
                        "v10.0",
                        0.29
                    ],

                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Safari",
                "id": "Safari",
                "data": [
                    [
                        "v11.0",
                        3.39
                    ],
                    [
                        "v10.1",
                        0.96
                    ],

                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Edge",
                "id": "Edge",
                "data": [
                    [
                        "v16",
                        2.6
                    ],
                    [
                        "v15",
                        0.92
                    ],

                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Opera",
                "id": "Opera",
                "data": [
                    [
                        "v50.0",
                        0.96
                    ],
                    [
                        "v49.0",
                        0.82
                    ],

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

[Here is a Fiddle showing what I mean.](https://jsfiddle.net/q71wrg8t/2/)

Is there a way that I can do this? Thank you in advance.

Edit: I cannot incorporate the answer in my actual code, I suspect because I a m using a for loop. My working code without coloration is below. I will update if I manage to implement the answer in this.

```
                "drilldown": {
                    "series": [

                      {% for each_space in Vacant_location_data %}

                        {
                            "name": "{{ each_space.loc_room }}",
                            "id": "{{ each_space.loc_room }}",

                            "data":[
                                [
                                    "Free space",
                                    {{ each_space.nempty }},

                                ],

                                [
                                    "Occupied Space",
                                    {{ each_space.occupied }}
                                ],

                            ]
                            ,

                        },

                        {% endfor %}
                    ]
                }
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s5uLfncr
(click Chrome to drilldown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now, you colored the whole series. But you can color each drilldown point individually like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rzfpho7a

```
"drilldown": {
"series": [{
    "name": "Chrome",
    "id": "Chrome",
    "data": [{
      name: "v65.0",
      y: 1,
      color: 'green'
    }, {
      name: "v64.0",
      y: 1.3,
      color: 'red'
    }]
  },
 .
 .
 .
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data

Comment: Thank you for this, it doesn't seem to be working for me on my end but it is in your fiddle so their must be something going wrong in my code. I'll update if its something more than something mistyped

Comment: Note that your data is an array of objects now, not an array of arrays. Let me know if that worked for you

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to implement a for loop with it. I'll paste my actual code in the question - I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: When you define series you might have too many brackets.
It should be series: [{name...  but not series: [{{name...
I don't know if this is a reason but you should check it

Comment: Thats a good heads up though I still cannot get it to work :(